# Trouble with drag functionality in an image slider (React, Next)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slider, draggable

I'm trying to recreate a JS draggable slider in React/Next from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/pen/MWXBRBp) but I just can't make it slide on mouse drag. Nothing happens on first click, but at the mouseUp event, the slider starts to slide and it won't stop until you reload the page.
Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hoover-owek2w?file=/src/App.js) so far.

And here is the original from codepen:

```
const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

const handleOnDown = e => track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;

const handleOnUp = () => {
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";  
  track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
}

const handleOnMove = e => {
  if(track.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;
  
  const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX,
        maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;
  
  const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
        nextPercentageUnconstrained = parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage,
        nextPercentage = Math.max(Math.min(nextPercentageUnconstrained, 0), -100);
  
  track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;
  
  track.animate({
    transform: `translate(${nextPercentage}%, -50%)`
  }, { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" });
  
  for(const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
    image.animate({
      objectPosition: `${100 + nextPercentage}% center`
    }, { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I was using onClick to activate dragging functionality, which was wrong. The correct event is onMouseDown.